# Minimal and characteristic polynomial of $\phi$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Let V be a vector space over a field F with a basis (e1, . . . , en), and the operator

$\phi : e_i = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        e_{i+1} & \mbox{if } i\ne j \\
        e_1 & \mbox{if } i=j
    \end{array}
\right.$

I want to show that the minimal polynomial of ϕ and its characteristic polynomial are both
equal to $t^n − 1$.
First at all I write the matrix of phi which is :

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & ...&...& 0 &1\\
1 & 0&&&&.\\
 0 &1&0&&&. \\
... & ... &...&...&...&.\\
0 &0&0&...&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

The I want to compute the characteristic polynomial which is :

det(t-$\phi$) = det$\begin{pmatrix}
t& 0 & ...&...& 0 &1\\
  1 & t&&&\\
 0 &1&t& \\
... & ... &...&...&...&...\\
 0 &0&0&...&t\\
 0 &0&0&...&1&t\\
\end{pmatrix}$

What can I do now?

Comment: You can explicitly calculate this determinant using Laplace expansion.

Comment: @tolUene I know but I don't know how to do since I don't know exactly the size of the matrix

Comment: Use the fact that large portions of the matrix are quite similar and try using induction.

Comment: There is a free $j$ in the definition of  $\phi$, but it is not mentioned anywhere else. Is this an error, and if so, should one read $n$ for $j$ or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively easy to see that $\phi$ shifts the coordinates one place cyclically, and only after $n$ applications will they be in their original positions. Hence we immediately get the characteristic and minimal polynomials as $t^n-1$.

Indeed the given matrix is a companion matrix for $t^n-1$, so it is its own rational canonical form consisting of one invariant factor.